# Is it possible to integrate SonarQube, Jenkins and GitLab (all in dockers)?

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube, gitlab

Currently, I am working in a quality process so as to ensure that the code is acceptable. For that, I'm integrating Jenkins, SonarQube and GitLab, which are running in different servers (actually they are in different docker containers).

The idea is to check with SonarQube everytime the code is pushed against GitLab and block commits, merges, and so on, whether SonarQube has not passed.

I have already integrated Jenkins with SonarQube, but Jenkins checks the code inside his workspace, so imagine a situation where a developer in his laptop needs to push his changes.

My conceptual question is simple: Is it possible to integrate these technologies in order to do this? And, if the question is yes, which steps are necessary?

PD: I don't need to see code, configuration files,and so on. I just need something like:

1. Configure SonarQube to work with Jenkins
2. Do an script so as to copy that file in that folder,
3. ...

Answer (score 2):

First, in docker means each tool is in its own container.
They only need to see each other through the network, which is where a [Docker Engine in Swarm mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) comes in.

Second "configure Jenkins to work with SonarQube"... that is what I have done in my shop, and there isn't much to it.
Once the [Jenkins SonarQube plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SonarQube+plugin) is installed, and the [address for the SonarQube server entered](http://mbaquick.blogspot.fr/2016/01/configure-jenkins-with-sonarqube-for_2.html), you can [configure your job](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins) and call sonar (for instance with maven: `$SONAR_MAVEN_GOAL -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL`)

The analysis done in the Jenkins workspace will then be published in the SonarQube server.

A swarm server is the more modern version of this 2015 [docker-compose.yml file](https://github.com/marcelbirkner/docker-ci-tool-stack/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) from the [`marcelbirkner/docker-ci-tool-stack`](https://github.com/marcelbirkner/docker-ci-tool-stack) project.

[image: https://github.com/marcelbirkner/docker-ci-tool-stack/raw/master/screenshots/docker-ci-tools.png]

The idea remains the same though: each element is isolated in its own container.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried It myself but https://gitlab.talanlabs.com/gabriel-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin could be interesting in your setup.